# Display notification with text box in linux using java

Tags: java, linux, gtk, gtk3, gnome-3

I want to build a messaging application, which displays a notification when a message is received with the text box to reply within notification using java

I'm noobie at GTK library, I can able to display the notification but, don't know how to display with a text box.

I have installed libjava-gnome-java using apt in ubuntu

Here is my sample code I tried to display a notification.

```
import org.gnome.gtk.Gtk;
import org.gnome.notify.Notification;
import org.gnome.notify.Notify;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gtk.init(args);

    Notify.init("My program name");

    Notification myNotification = new Notification("My notification title","My notification body","dialog-information");
    myNotification.show();
}
}
```

Thanks in advance